# How to Exposing secure rest/soap service in Mule, require best and simple approach

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

In My flow, I have many HTTP Rest API call, I have used key-store (as below) which is fine for internal api calls. Now I need to expose rest/soap service to external api. Which is the simple and best way to secure mule api. I'm using Mule 3.5.1 Version.

```
<https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS"
    cookieSpec="netscape" receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0"
    sendBufferSize="0" socketSoLinger="0" validateConnections="false"
    clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" enableCookies="true">
    <https:tls-key-store path="cer/check.jks"
        keyPassword="abc" storePassword="abc" />
</https:connector>

 <flow name="service" doc:name="service">
    <https:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" responseTransformer-refs="ReponseProperty"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <logger message="***Invoke****#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
 <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
     <component class="com.services.CallImpl"/>
     <jersey:exception-mapper class="com.util.JerseyExceptionMapper"/>
</jersey:resources> 
<byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
```

So that external api calls, shouldn't interfere with other mule services.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want simple way, **basic authentication** is there which is very simple, but it is based on Transport layer, but yes simple to implement

reference :-http://confluex.com/blog/http-inbound-endpoint-basic-authentication/ 
,

You can also use **oauth 2.0** for securing your service where you need to **validate** the **token** before a client can access your rest service
refernce :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Creating+an+OAuth+2.0a+Web+Service+Provider
 and 
http://ricston.com/blog/oauth-server-mule/
also you can refer :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+STS+OAuth+2.0a+Example+Application

Other options are **JWT**(JSON Web Token) in your Mule api, where you need to generate the Token and validate it to access your service..

reference :- http://jwt.io/

But again here you need to do a lot of Java coding to generate the token and validating it

Comment: Thank you (Planning to go by 1 or 2).Apart from these provided above. Is there others ways  also present to  secure API which Mule  is providing. Looking for knowledge based, so that can explore more.

Comment: Mule basically provides oauth 2.0 for enterprise edition and basic authentication for community edition for REST services ... There may be other approach out of box which Mule supports or recommends .. But these 2 approaches are basically implemented in case of exposing Rest in Mule